# How to set/get value of check box

Tags: laravel

I have this 2 checkboxes, first checkbox has a value of 1 while the second one has value of 2. How can I get the value if both checkboxes are checked, I want to get a value of 3 if both checkboxes are checked, How can I get that and save it?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" />  // 1
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="2" />  // 2
// if both are checked then value is 3, how can i get that and then save it?
```

Comment: You need to treat them as "arrays". `name="test[]"` if you are submitting it to a controller. Then you can use `array_sum($request->test)`.

Comment: I checked the two checkboxes and I got this..

array:2 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
]

how can I set the value to 3 and save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the input so it will become an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="2" />
```

Now on the controller side you can get the sum of the values of the array:

```
$sum = array_sum($request->input('test', []));
```

If anything is checked those values will end up being in an array. If nothing is checked, `test` isn't passed in the request at all, we will use a default of an empty array and would get a sum of 0.

Comment: thank you so much I got the value (3) now, can you please explain a bit why? I'm a little confused I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1):

First, use name in the array as it refers to same checkbox and a group checkbox.

**In Javascript**

```
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="1" /> 
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="test" value="2" />
```

For modern browsers:

```
var checkedValue = document.querySelector('.messageCheckbox:checked').value;
```

By using jQuery:

```
var checkedValue = $('.messageCheckbox:checked').val();
```

Now for both get the sum of the values.

Pure javascript without jQuery:

```
var checkedValue = 0; 
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('messageCheckbox');
for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
  if(inputElements[i].checked){
       checkedValue += parseInt(inputElements[i].value, 10);
  }
}
console.log(checkedValue);
```

**In Controller**

$sum = array_sum($request->input('test', []));